# Rollback updated data in table in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update, rollback

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and in my database I have by mistake updated all the data in one table and all the records in one column are updated and I want to get back those data which was updated.

Is it any query or something rollback functionality to get those data back?

Comment: As long as the transaction hasn't been committed yet - you can issue a `ROLLBACK` and undo your changes. Or then you'll have to restore a backup from before the incident

Comment: marc_s, I do not have any backup but still I just want to get back those data which I have by mistakley updated.

Comment: If you still have the transaction open (`BEGIN TRANSACTION ..... UPDATE ......`) then you can do a `ROLLBACK` - otherwise you need to fix this manually.

Comment: No actually I update all the data without using transaction so I can not rollback now It's ok I'll have to do it manully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Solved]

I have used APEX SQL to recover my lost data just installed and connect to my database and rollback my lost data.

It's just simple now.

[APEX SQL](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/recover-sql-server-data-from-accidental-updates/)

Answer (score 0):

Restore the latest backup done before the incident into a new database (RestoredDatabase for example). Then update the column from the restored database using a statement similar to the following:

```
USE MyDatabase
GO

UPDATE T
   SET T.TheColumn = S.TheColumn
FROM
   TheTable T INNER JOIN RestoredDatabase.dbo.TheTable S
      ON T.Id = S.Id
```

Comment: I do not have any backup so what to do. I just want to get back those data which I have by mistakley updated.

Comment: What is the recovery model of the database? If it's simple, I'm afraid there is no solution. If it's full, you will need to use a third party tool to read the transaction log to get the information back.